# Is it possible to get Google authenticator on Mobile and computer at the same time?

Tags: google-authenticator

I use google authenticator to log in to websites with 2fa i have to go to mobile app whenever I want to see the 2fa code, I want to get it directly from my computer. Is it possible somehow?

What i want is that i can access authenticator from my computer and mobile at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean? How would Google know that you are you on your phone and you are you on your computer? You would have to authenticate for that right?

Comment: I use google authenticator to login to websites with 2fa i would have to go to mobile app whenever I want to see the 2fa code, I want to get it directly from my computer. What i want is that i can access authenticator from my computer and mobile at the same time.

Comment: I just found "Authy" which is much better solution than this as it lets me use both devices.

Answer (score 0):

So I Googled that for you:
https://www.google.nl/search?client=ms-android-google&ei=q9TZWYbaFdGiwAKjjZtA&q=google+authenticator+for+windows&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.1.41l3.0.0.0.3454.1.1.0.1.1.0.0.0..1.0....0...1..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.1.12.3...110.anFAezNz27s

And this article (first Google result) https://www.google.nl/amp/s/www.maketecheasier.com/google-authenticator-windows/amp/ describes that it is written on an open standard and that there are Windows programs like WinAuth, you can download to use Google Authenticator.

Comment: Thanks but I just found "Authy" which is much better solution than this as it lets me use both devices.

Comment: ive tried downloading winAuth - ive already got google authenticator on my phone - but the secret that google generates to input into WinAuth never matches the codes google authenticator generates, so it doesnt seem to work